# How to export the result set of a postgres query in a format that is importable with psql?

Tags: postgresql, psql, pgadmin

Using psql is there a way to do a select statement where the output is a list of insert statements so that I can execute those insert statements somewhere else.

```
SELECT * FROM foo where some_fk=123;
```

Should output

```
INSERT INTO foo 
(column1,column2,...) VALUES 
('abc','xyyz',...),
('aaa','cccc',...),
 .... ;
```

That I can redicet to a file say `export.sql` which I can then import with `psql -f export.sql`
My goal is to move export the result of a select statement in a format that I can import into another database instance with exactly the same table structure.

Comment: Why not `COPY` to/from CSV file?

Comment: @IgorRomanchenko I only want a subset of the table, not sure how COPY can be used to restrict to a subset of the table, can you provide an example how COPY to/from a CSV can be used.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Have a look at the `--inserts` option of `pg_dump`

```
pg_dump -t your_table --inserts -f somefile.txt your_db
```

Edit the resulting file if necessary.

For a subset, as IgorRomanchenko mentioned, you can use COPY with a SELECT statement.

Example of COPYing as CSV.

```
COPY (select * from table where foo='bar') TO '/path/to/file.csv' CSV HEADER
```

Comment: That will dump the whole table, I want a subset of the table, the result set of a select query against the table being dumped.